# Dynamically build div on button click when button is also created dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

Working hard on my angular skills. stackoverflow has been really helpfull on getting my first own app together.

My app uses a service::
collectable.service.ts:

```
export class CollectableService {
    private collectables: Collectable[] = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "someName",
            faseOne: false,
            faseTwo: true,
            contact: "Someones name",
            email: 'email1@test.com'
        },            {
            id: 2,
            name: "someOneElseName",
            faseOne: true,
            faseTwo: false,
            contact: "Someone Elses name",
            email: 'email2@test.com'
        },

    getCollectables() {
        return this.collectables;
    }
]
```

My component.html:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="btn-group m-3" *ngFor="let item of collectables | pipeOne">
    <button class="btn btn-success">{{item.name}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="dynamicDiv"></div> // here I want to show the rest of the values out of the array
```

Example pipeOne (I have one pipe per fase):

```
  transform(pipeOne: any[], ...args: unknown[]): any[] {
    return pipeOne.filter(p => p.faseOne == true);
  }
```

Now when the button is clicked, I want to display the other values of the object in the array into div #dynamicDiv. In this example because of faseOne equals true, I need access to the values of the first object in the array, with ID 1.
So I can display only the values of object id 1

```
<div id="dynamicDiv>
    <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{item.contact}}</h2>
</div>
```

etc...

Hope you guys understand and can help me get further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one more property to your component as `selectedItem`, and assign it on button click, for example;

```js
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  selectedItem: Collectable;
}
```

And in your `MyComponent` template

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="btn-group m-3" *ngFor="let item of collectables | pipeOne">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)='selectedItem=item'>{{item.name}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf='selectedItem'>
    <h1>{{selectedItem.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{selectedItem.contact}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to do this to make it work:
selectedItem!: Collectable;

With a non-null assertion operator. Otherwise I'd get this error Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Thanks again